# Why is Bobby Munson's cut different than everyone else's?

Tags: character, sons-of-anarchy

Did they ever explain in the TV series *Sons Of Anarchy* why Bobby Munson's cut (his gang jacket) has a border around the shoulders?  There's a white pattern around what would be his sleeves (if it wasn't a vest) and that pattern isn't on any other character's vests, including all of the characters who are no longer in the show.

[image]

Comment: He also wears a lot of jean stuff and IIRC he wears a jean style cut too. The group is allowed to customize (to a point) their cuts. For example, Jax has a patch to memorize Opie. Opie's dad Piney also wore a jean style cut. This may be a relic of an older style within the club. The white trim may have been from the style back when JT was the president.

Comment: @DustinDavis - I left your edit, but he's more often referred to as Bobby Vegas than Bobby Munson.

Comment: @JohnnyBones Can you provide a reference to that? I haven't heard anyone call him that or at least I've never noticed. Are you sure you don't mean "Elvis" ? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bobby_Munson

Comment: @DustinDavis - That was probably me having a brain fart.  :o)  The point is, even *he* refers to himself as "Bobby Elvis" (like when he called Jury to get the intel on the two kids that got killed, not knowing one of them was Jury's son).

Comment: I know that this won't answer your question about Bobby's cut but it does about the whole Bobby Elvis thing. Bobby is referred to as Bobby Elvis early in season 4. AUSDA Potter called him that while briefing Sheriff Roosevelt about the RICO case. Fairly certain that there are a few other instances in the early seasons.

Comment: No idea about the embroidered vest hems. But he is referred to as Bobby Elvis early on in season one. He is seen in two or three episodes as an Elvis impersonator. Once at a school fundraiser, another at a Bar Mitzva and even travels out of town with Jax to Nevada to do a show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to a post on [this website](http://www.reddit.com/r/Sonsofanarchy/comments/kucjf/question_is_there_a_difference_in_meaningstatus/) (which obviously can't be confirmed), the embroidery indicates a status of Treasurer, which Bobby held.  In addition, I have found a photo which indicates that it's not unthinkable for Bobby to have a jacket with a border:

[image]

So, while not conclusive about exactly *why* his cut is different, we can at least know that it wasn't some wardrobe mistake for him to have it.